# jquery change background-image of a <section> when a carousel slider changes its 'active' state

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I am trying to change my  background-image when a nested boostrap carousel changes its .active class to another element. Having trouble getting my jQuery to work and was wanting to consult you the interwebs on how to do this properly. I believe my problem lies within my jQuery. Take a look! Thanks in advance for the help!

**HTML:**

```
<section id="testimonial" class="padding-top-bottom image-bg light-typo">

        <div class="container">

            <div class="testimonial">
                <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide bs-docs-carousel-example" data-interval="10000">
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3" class=""></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="4" class=""></li>
                    </ol>
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="item active">
                            <h1>“Grip Clean does a great job of cleaning up your hands after a messy afternoon of bike maintenance, does not dry out your skin, and was created by one of our own. Why use anything else?”</h1>
                            <br>
                            <h3>– Transworld Motocross Magazine</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">

                            <h1>“The best hand soap ever – you guys gotta try it.”</h1>
                            <br>
                            <h3>– Jeremy Stenberg</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <h1>“Grip Clean is a complete hit here at our shop. All of the guys are saying it’s the best stuff they’ve ever used.”</h1>
                            <br>
                            <h3>–Subaru Rally Team USA</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <h1>“I love this soap.<br>Its helped me clean up after a long day of lawn work.” </h1>
                            <br>
                            <h3>– Matt Hoffman</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <h1>“This stuff is rad, I didn’t know something this good could exist.”</h1>
                            <br>
                            <h3>– Robbie Maddison </h3>
                        </div>




                    </div>
                    <br><br><br>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="overlay-bg"></div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

**CSS:**

```
.bg-one{
background-image: url(../img/subaru-slider/Sub_420.jpg) !important;
}

.bg-two{
    background-image: url(../img/subaru-slider/Sub_424.jpg) !important;
}
```

**JS/jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if( $(".carousel-inner :nth-child(1)").hasClass("active")){
        $("#testimonial").addClass("bg-one");
    }
    if( $(".carousel-inner :nth-child(2)" ).hasClass("active") ){
        $("#testimonial").addClass("bg-two").removeClass("bg-one");

    }

    });
```

Thanks again for any input on this issue! Trying to reach a deadline and am stumped!

Answer (score 1):

You jQuery code is only being called one time, during the `document ready` event. You want to attach that code to an event when the carousel changes slides:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
    // ...
  })
});
```

Check out the Bootstrap documentation for the [Carousel Events](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-events) for more information.

Comment: This solution actually worked a lot better for my scenario than the solution posted below this. Thank Quantastical!

Answer (score 0):

It's not working as you expect because your code has no way of knowing when the class has changed. `$(document).ready()` only fires once, not every time something changes.

You'll need to use events. This code is not complete but points you in the right direction, namely with `trigger()`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // bind event listener
    $("#testimonial").bind('cssClassChanged', className, function(){ 
      // you can do stuff in response to the "triggered" event here. You know the className since it is being passed in. 
    });  

    if( $(".carousel-inner :nth-child(1)").hasClass("active")){
        $("#testimonial").addClass("bg-one");
        // trigger event when the calss has been set
        $("#testimonial").trigger("cssClassChanged", "bg-one");

    }
    if( $(".carousel-inner :nth-child(2)" ).hasClass("active") ){
        $("#testimonial").addClass("bg-two").removeClass("bg-one");

    }

    });
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a little further? I am not familiar with bind() or trigger(). What type of code goes in the anon function in the bind()?

Comment: the anon function in bind() just does whatever you want to happen once the class has been changed. `.bind()` tells jQuery "listen for an event" (like a mouse click, etc.), or in this case, a custom event (named `cssClassChanged`). `trigger()` is what actually causes the custom event to fire.

Comment: and className in the bind() is doing what exactly? I'm sorry for so many noob questions :(

Comment: that's just some data you're passing along with the event. See in the trigger, where it says `"bg-one"`? that's just passing it as a parameter. Try reading up on jquery docs on bind and trigger. It's useful stuff to know. :)

Comment: Also I am going to be having this carousel change between 5 background-images with 5 if statements

Comment: Thanks Prefix! I'm going to try and use this info to get this working. I very much appreciate your help!

Comment: @Emericas you're welcome! No worries about the beginner questions everyone starts somewhere. Have a good night.

Comment: One more quick question: So when the className is being triggered (In the example "bg-one") it will insert that class name into the anon function in the bind?